# Collecting ArrayList element groups into another ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, point

I have Point-s for the coordinates of buildings.
I put them into an ArrayList called **houseList**.

```
ArrayList<Point> houseList = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

When all the houses are in the houseList, I add the houseList to the **cityList** which is an ArrayList too.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>> cityList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();

.
.
.
cityList.add(houseList);
houseList.clear();
```

There are more cities to add to this cityList, so I clear the houseList, so that I can fill it again with another city's buildings.

But as I can see, when I clear the houseList, it removes the elements from the cityList too.

What would be the correct method to collect cities from buildings which have point-coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `clear()` and re-use that object. When you add an object to a list, it is not a *copy* of your object that is added to the list, it's just a *reference*.

Thus, clearing would cause that reference, that still points to the same object, to show you cleared object. Any new content will be reflected in that reference.

The correct way is to assign a new list to the variable `houseList`. It will then be a different object and the old reference will look at the old object which is no longer going to change.

```
cityList.add(houseList);
houseList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Point>>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Java objects work pretty much like real objects.

If you fill a bucket with water. Then put the bucket into a box. Then empty the bucket to fill it with milk, the box will contain a bucket full of milk.

You want two different buckets: one with water, and one with milk. So, instead of emptying the first bucket, you need to leave it as is, but take a `new` one and fill it with milk.

```
cityList.add(houseList); // add the water bucket to the box
houseList = new ArrayList<>(); // get a new bucket
houseList.add(otherHouse); // add milk to the new bucket
cityList.add(houseList); // add the milk bucket to the box
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add it, you should clone the ArrayList of houses, like so:

```
cityList.add(houseList.clone())
```

This way, a new copy is made and passed to the city =, instead of a reference to the ArrayList that you clear

Comment: Use of `clone()` is strongly discouraged.

Comment: Instead of cloning it and clearing it, why not just make a new ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

When you put a `houseList` into `cityList`, it doesn't make a copy - you haven't actually *put* it into `cityList`, you've just put a *reference* to it in there.

You are using the *same* list over and over again, so when you clear it, all your points are removed.

The simplest way to solve this is to create a new empty `ArrayList` for each `houseList`, and add each one in turn into your `cityList`.